# How can I convert this date format?

Tags: javascript, date

An API I use provides a date in the object like `2018-02-14T17:00:00`. How can I convert this to make it say: `Tuesday, February 14th 7:00 pm`

I know how to use `.getMonth()` methods on a date object but is it possible to do something similar with a string in a date format like this in Javascript?

Comment: What have you tried ? `Format string to date` then `Format date`

Answer (score 4):

You can use [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/docs/) to format the date object.

```js
console.log(new moment('2018-02-14T17:00:00').format('dddd, MMMM Do h:mm a'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the string into separated values first using String.split() method.

```
let rawDate = '2018-02-14T17:00:00';
let date = rawDate.split("T")[0]; //2018-02-14
let time = rawDate.split("T")[1]; //17:00:00

let year = date.split("-")[0],
  month = date.split("-")[1],
  day = date.split("-")[2];

let hr = time.split(":")[0],
  mm = time.split(":")[1],
  ss = time.split(":")[2];
```

Now just format these separated values using `new Date(year, month, day)` etc.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
    console.log(new moment('2018-02-14T17:00:00').format('LLLL'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript natively does not provide a way for you to stringify a date with a provided format.

To do that, you can use moment.js. Here's the specific documentation that says how to do that:

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/